# Reusing compiled Theano functions

Tags: c++, python-2.7, theano

Suppose I have implemented the following function in Theano:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x + y
f = function([x, y], z)
```

When I try to run it a graph of computations is constructed, the function gets optimized and compiled.

How can I reuse this compiled chunk of code from within a Python script and/or a C++ application?

**EDIT:**
The goal is to construct a deep learning network and reuse it in a final C++ app.

Comment: It appears that Theano caches optimization results so any subsequent call should be pretty quick. Still, after e.g. workstation restart you have to go through optimization again. Pickling solves the issue. After compiling a Theano function object you can pickle it and then load whenever necessary.

Comment: But can I call the pickled function from C/C++ code?

Comment: You can try loading it with [Boost.Python pickle interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html) but I'm not sure if you can use it without python. As @nouiz pointed out below, you can always call python code from within C++ and use the pickled object from there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: I'm not there yet. I'll update as soon as I have some news. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible. There is user that modified Theano to allow pickling the Theano function, but during unpickling we already re optimize the graph.

There is a Pull Request that allow Theano to generate a C++ library. The user can then compile it himself and use it as a normal C++ library. The lib links against the python lib and requires numpy to be installed. But this isn't ready for broad usage.

What is your goal? To save on the compilation time? If so Theano already caches the c++ module that it compiles, so the next time it is reused, the compilation will be faster. But for a big graph, the optimization phase is always redone as told above, and this can take a significant time.

So what is your goal?

This is something that we are working on. Make sure to use the latest Theano release (0.6) as it compiles faster. The development version is also a little faster.

Comment: I have added the goal to the original question. Guess I'll have to go with lua for the time being.

Comment: You can call python code from C++. This would allow you to do what you want. But it request that python, NumPy and Theano are installed. Not ideal for redistribution, but if you control the environment it can work.

Comment: Would you post a link to the PR?

Comment: Here is the issues with some notes: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/1408 . There is not clear instruction. If you have questions, you will have faster answer on the theano-dev mailing list.