# Can I use Theano with C++?

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I've been using the Theano library in Python and had some success, although my main program where I'm extracting sections of images to classify is written in C++. Is there any way to call Theano via C++ or is it only built for Python?

Comment: this might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112016/reusing-compiled-theano-functions

Comment: http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html
This is about wrapping C++ for PYTHON.